# dynamically added class can't be called

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to accomplish delete in page which is filled with data by ajax call. 
my page has this before data is loaded:

```
<span id="ShowSelectedCategories"></span>
```

and after ajax call i fill with below info:

```
function(data){
    $('#ShowSelectedCategories').prepend('<a href="" id="'+b.SelectedCategoriesID+'" class="DeleteCat"> x <span style="color:red">' + data +'</span> </a>&nbsp ');
}
```

and finally after click i want to remove clicked element but it doesn't work.

```
$(function(){

    $("#ShowSelectedCategories").click(function(e){
    e.target.outerHTML //this is the part i want to remove after click

e.preventDefault();
    })
```

I have tried `$(".DeleteCat).click()` but this gave error because elements with that class was created dynamically.

Your help is appreciated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$('#ShowSelectedCategories').on('click', '.DeleteCat', function(e){
    $(this).remove();
    e.preventDefault();
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Dj5NQ/

Comment: that worked. thanks bunch. what is idea behind this using on function?

Comment: `on` indicates an event delegate. Since you're adding `.DeleteCat` elements dynamically, you would either need to bind a new click handler to each of them (not a great idea), or delegate the event to a parent element. Since events bubble up the DOM, when you click on a child node, the parent of that node will also receive the click event. The second parameter indicates that we only want to call the event handler (the third parameter) when the click event has bubbled from an element with class `DeleteCat`

Comment: @user1623481, when you just bind the `click` event like you did, it is only binding to the elements that match your selector when the javascript is initially run.  Anything added to the DOM after you bind that 'click' event wasn't included in the selector initially.  Using `.on` dynamically binds the event to the selected elements, so if an element is added to the DOM that matches the selector you used when calling `.on`, it will bind the event to it.

Comment: thanks again for the explanation. it is nice of you to share your knowledge.

Comment: @Gromer Technically `on` binds the event only to the primary selector. If there are no elements matching the primary selector when `on` is called, nothing will happen. But, because it is only creating one event listener (instead of one for each element), you get the pleasant side-effect of increased performance. But the point I want to make is that it's not binding anything to the nodes added dynamically.

Answer (score 5):

Try `$(e.target).remove()`,

```
$("#ShowSelectedCategories").click(function(e){
         $(e.target).remove();    
         e.preventDefault();
});
```

If you want to delete element with class DeleteCat within span with id ShowSelectedCategories then you can do it like this,

```
$("#ShowSelectedCategories").on("click", "DeleteCat" function(e){
         $(this).remove();    
         e.preventDefault();
});
```

Comment: it leaves the "x"s I have tried $(e.target.outerHTML).remove(); but this didn't work. I need something removes whole part which was added with append (start to end a href)

Answer (score 1):

Use something like this to call dynamically added class

```
$('.class').live("click", function(){

  $('#id').remove();   


});
```