# jQuery: stumped while trying to select dynamically created span

Tags: javascript, jquery, onclick

I have a dynamically created `<span class="remove-row">`, and I can't get the `click()` event to fire.  Being relatively green in JS still, I'm ***guessing*** my problem is with my selector.

It can all be seen **[here on jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mOrloff/48nbs/21/)**.
(see the very bottom of the JS pane)

Here's a skinny version of what the **generated** html looks like:

```
...
<section >
    <div class="look-like-input textfield droppable" restrict-children="1" id="">
        <span class="remove-row"><span>X</span></span>
    </div>
    <br />
    <div class="look-like-input textarea droppable" id="deprecated"></div>
</section>
...
```

And this is how I'm ***trying*** to get the click event:

```
...
$(".remove-row").click(function() {
    alert("Hello");
});
```

Comment: Description of event delegation which will solve your problem: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13090887/jquery-does-not-select-jquery-added-element/13090983#13090983

Comment: check out the answer by Richard Dillman with the jsfiddle link I made. You're very close but need to specify a proper container for your event delegation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because `.click` gets bound when the page is ready, use `.on` to allow for the bind to happen as the items get added to the dom.  While `.live` would work, it has been deprecated.

```
$("#drop-zone").on('click', '.remove-row', function() {
    alert("Hello");
});
```

Drop zone id is added for efficiency and scope limiting.

http://jsfiddle.net/48nbs/22/

Comment: just to be clear, starting your function call at $(document) will force .on() to work like live or delegate,  if you start the call at $('remove-row') it will only operate on those items already in the page when the dom becomes ready. $(document) also executes faster.

Answer (score 1):

Consider using:

```
jQuery(".remove-row").on("click", function () {alert('hello');});
```

Comment: Live is deprecated as of jQuery 1.7 in favor of on(), for older version delegate() is recommended
http://api.jquery.com/live/

Comment: `.live()` has been deprecated since 1.7 and removed in 1.9 which just came out. Youu should use `.on()` instead. Otherwise, this is probably the correct answer :)

Answer (score 1):

try using on() like this :

```
$(".remove-row").on('click',function() {
    alert("Hello");
});
```

this will take care of dynamically created elements.

you can use live() too but
 `live()` is deprecated As of jQuery 1.7 --http://api.jquery.com/live/

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem. This worked for me:

$(".remove-row").on("click", function () { alert('hello'); } );

Or the .live version purposed by Amd4632 should work too.

Answer (score 0):

It's possible that you're generating the html after the code to set the listener has already executed. In that case, the listener will never get attached to the dynamically generated span element.

**Edit**:
 
In fact, I just checked out your fiddle and I do not see the script code to set the listener anywhere. I'm assuming that you execute the code once the page loads. In that case, if the DOM elements have not been generated yet, the listener will not get attached.