# Access dynamically added elements in Jquery

Tags: jquery, html

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [dynamically added class can’t be called](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12482336/dynamically-added-class-cant-be-called)
>   [jquery does not select jquery added element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13090887/jquery-does-not-select-jquery-added-element)

I'm trying to access dynamically added element via class name but couldn't.

Sample HTML:

```
<div class="foo">static foo (click to trigger alert)</div>
<br />
<br />
<a id="add">add dynamic foo</a>
<br />
<div id="items"></div>
```

Sample Jquery:

```
$(function(){

    var c = 1;

    $('#add').click(function() {

        $('#items').append('<div style="background:red" id="item' + c + '">\n\
                                Hello World ' + c + '\n\
                            </div>\n\
                            <div class="foo">dynamic foo ' + c + 'clicking me should alert?</a>');

        c++;

    });

    $('.foo').click(function() {
        alert('tst');
    });

});
```

**Demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/D3gGH/

As you can see in the demo, clicking the dynamically added `<div class="foo">` should trigger alert but it doesn't. How to do it properly?

Comment: Duplicate of the entire related section on the right as well as the list you got when entering the question title

Comment: use **on()** instead of **click()**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `on` instead `click`

```
$(function(){

    var c = 1;

    $('#add').click(function() {

        $('#items').append('<div style="background:red" id="item' + c + '">\n\
                                Hello World ' + c + '\n\
                            </div>\n\
                            <div class="foo">dynamic foo ' + c + 'clicking me should alert?</a>');

        c++;

    });

    $(document).on('click','.foo', function(e) {
        alert('tst');
    });

});​
```

[Working DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/D3gGH/1/)

Answer (score 0):

Use **event delegation** when dealing with dynamically created elements, and try to *avoid excessive use of document or document.body for delegated events on large documents* - see [reference](http://api.jquery.com/on/).

```
$('#items').on("click", ".foo", function() {
    alert('tst');
});
```